# Por que mi cod. no genera números aleatorios?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Según yo esto debería generar "hp" aleatorio mas el hp base que esta en la variable, pero los resultados terminan siendo los mismos para los 3 tipos de "modificadores"
Por ejemplo cada vez que invoque a mod_peso() debería retornar algo asi :

```
 mod_peso()
(104.4, 'Pequeño')
 mod_peso()
(101.2, 'Pequeño')
 mod_peso()
(116, 'Normal')
 mod_peso()
(174.0, 'Gran')
 mod_peso()
(106.5, 'Pequeño')
 mod_peso()
(155.0, 'Gran')
```

es decir distintos HP's pero me salen iguales por cada tipo... qué hice mal?

```
import random

def mod_peso():
     dat_1 = ["Gran", "Normal", "Pequeño"]
     mod = dat_1[ran(0, len(dat_1) -1)]
     if mod == "Normal":
              hp = hp_base
              return hp, "Normal"
     elif mod == "Gran":
              hp = hp_base + (hp_base * 0.5)
              return hp, "Gran"
     elif mod == "Pequeño":
              hp = hp_base - (hp_base * 0.1)
              return hp, "Pequeño"
def ran(x, y):
    n = random.randint(x, y)
    return n

hp_base = 100 + ran(10.0, 20.0)
mod_peso()
```

Comment: He probado y a mí no me salen nunca dos valores iguales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que `hp_base` es inicializado una sola vez, por lo que llamadas sucesivas a `mod_peso()` puede devolver diferentes pesos cualitativos (Pequeño, Normal y Gran) pero para cada uno de ellos el valor será siempre el mismo.

Para ilustrarlo con un ejemplo
`hp_base` es calculado y vale 110
Se llama a `mod_peso()` y el `mod` es "Normal"

```
if mod == "Normal":
          hp = hp_base
          return hp, "Normal"
```

Por lo que `mod_peso()` devuelve 110.

Si seguimos llamando a `mod_peso()` en algún momento `mod` volverá a ser "Normal" y a menos que hayamos cambiado `hp_base` el código volverá a devolver 110.

Esto pasa por cada valor de `dat_1`.

Comment: No soluciono mi problema en un principio, pero me hiciste refrescar las cosas... (Solucionado)